# nuxt how to have a question mark after the page name

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have this setup:

```
pages/
--| search/
-----| _index.vue
```

And I want to have a url like this:

```
myApp.com/search/?parameter=1
```

But when I manually put `?parameter=1` into url after `search` it tells me `This page could not be found`. How can I achieve routing such that after `/` I can have `?` without no errors?

Comment: Be sure to not mix `query string` and `URL params`. Here, you need to have access to the `query string`. If you want to use it the `params` way, your URL will be like `/search/1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your _index.vue to _id.vue which is the nuxt default

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-wave-cjqp7?file=/pages/search/_id.vue

Comment: This works but this is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: @kissu of course I know, but did you understand his question?

Comment: Yeah, I understand what he meant. I also can see that he had some issue in his page. Not sure what this is. Looking at his other questions here, it looks like he is trying to make some search functionality, hence having an `_id` is not the way to go. Also, if you know that this is not the way to go, why suggesting it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the clean way to go for this one.

`/pages/search-page.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>This is the search page</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SearchPage',
  mounted() {
    console.log('query >>', this.$route.query.search)
  },
}
</script>
```