# nuxt. going to search page by this.$router.push clears URL query parameters

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to go to my search page in nuxt `myApp.com/search?parameter=1` from my main page. In the main page I can go to search page in two ways, by using a nuxt-link:

```html
<NuxtLink
  :to="`/search?parameter=${number}`"
>
</NuxtLink>
```

Or I can go with a method:

```js
goToSearch() {
  this.$router.push(`/search?parameter=${this.number}`);
},
```

When I use the `nuxt-link` and land on search page the url is correct with parameter: `myApp.com/search?parameter=1`
But when I use my method which is conencted to a button in the page and I land on search page the url becomes `myApp.com/search` which is problematic for me!

Please note I have two have both the method and the nuxt-link. How can I fix it so when I use the method and go to search page I keep the parameters?

Comment: I have a different working aka `search-page` rather than `search` and `search` rather than  `parameter` (because this is not a parameter and because it's more friendly for the end user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this, as mentioned [in the documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link-props)

```html
<nuxt-link :to="{ path: 'search-page', query: { search: number } }">
  Try search page
</nuxt-link>
```

You can also use it this way, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

```html
<button @click="$router.push({ path: 'search-page', query: { search: number } })">
  Try some other way
</button>
```

A correct `/pages/search-page.vue` page can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68127165/8816585).

Comment: Great. One question, with your changes my URL looks like `myApp.com/search-page?search=number`. How can I make it look like this: `myApp.com/search-page?number` ? thanks!

Comment: You can't do that because you're mixing things. There is: `/search-page?search=4`or `/search-page/4`but no middle ground. For a search, the first one is far more common and logic for the end user. @seyet

Comment: got it mate. I modified it the way you suggest it and it works fine, but the main issue persists, when I use `@click` it goes to search page and then reset the route object. It does't happen when using `nuxt-link`. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you make a [repro]? Should work properly.

Comment: I realized what the issue is, it's not `@click`! Basically the event I wanted to use was for when enter key is pressed and that is making problems. What I need to do is when user type something in the input and presses enter it should go to that route. The route is correct the way you have implemented it!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue as the OP, however, I resolved the issue by preventing the default click action, using @click.prevent, for example:

```html
<button @click.prevent="$router.push({ path: 'search-page', query: { search: number } })">
  Try some other way
</button>
```

I hope saves someone hours of soul searching!